# Trying to make a box move around the screen with the arrow keys

Tags: efficiency

I have a box and it moves around the screen when the user presses the arrow keys. It seems a bit bulky and awkward though. Any thoughts on how to make it more efficient/less resource intensive?

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Box {

private float boxWidth, boxHeight;
private int gameWidth, gameHeight;
private Color boxColor;

private Vector2 position;
private Vector2 velocity;
private Vector2 acceleration;

private boolean goRight, goLeft, goUp, goDown, stopRight, stopLeft, stopUp, stopDown;

public Box(int boxWidth, int boxHeight, Color boxColor, int gameWidth, int gameHeight) {
    this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
    this.boxHeight = boxHeight;
    this.boxColor = boxColor;

    this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight;

    position = new Vector2(gameWidth/2 - boxWidth/2, gameHeight/2 - boxHeight/2);
    velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
    acceleration = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

public void update(float delta) {

    velocity.add(acceleration.cpy().scl(delta));

    if(velocity.x >= 100) {
        velocity.x = 100;
    }

    if(velocity.x <= -100) {
        velocity.x = -100;
    }

    if(velocity.y <= -100) {
        velocity.y = -100;
    }

    if(velocity.y >= 100) {
        velocity.y = 100;
    }

    if(stopRight) {
        if(velocity.x > 0) {
            velocity.x -= velocity.x/20;
            if(velocity.x <= 0) {
                velocity.x = 0;
                stopRight = false;
            }
            if(goLeft) {
                acceleration.x = -100;
            }
        }
        else {};
    }

    if(stopLeft) {
        if(velocity.x < 0) {
            velocity.x -= velocity.x/20;
            if(velocity.x >= 0) {
                velocity.x = 0;
                stopLeft = false;
            }
            if(goRight) {
                acceleration.x = 100;
            }
        }
    }

    if(stopUp) {
        if(velocity.y < 0) {
            velocity.y -= velocity.y/20;
            if(velocity.y >= 0) {
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
            if(goDown) {
                acceleration.y = 100;
            }
        }
    }

    if(stopDown) {
        if(velocity.y > 0) {
            velocity.y -= velocity.y/20;
            if(velocity.y <= 0) {
                velocity.y = 0;
            }
            if(goUp) {
                acceleration.y = -100;
            }
        }
    }

    if(position.x >= gameWidth - boxWidth) {
        position.x = gameWidth - boxWidth;
    }

    if(position.x <= 0) {
        position.x = 0;
    }

    if(position.y >= gameHeight - boxHeight) {
        position.y = gameHeight - boxHeight;
    }

    if(position.y <= 0) {
        position.y = 0;
    }

    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));

}

public Box getBox() {
    return this;
}

public Color getBoxColor() {
    return boxColor;
}

public void goRight() {
    goRight = true;
    acceleration.x = 100;
    stopRight = false;
}

public void goLeft() {
    goLeft = true;
    acceleration.x = -100;
    stopLeft = false;
}
public void goUp() {
    goUp = true;
    acceleration.y = -200;
    stopUp = false;
}
public void goDown() {
    goDown = true;
    acceleration.y = 200;
    stopDown = false;
}

public float xPos() {
    return position.x;
}

public float yPos() {
    return position.y;
}

public void stopRight() {
    acceleration.x = 0;
    stopRight = true;
    goRight = false;
}

public void stopLeft() {
    acceleration.x = 0;
    stopLeft = true;
    goLeft = false;
}

public void stopUp() {
    acceleration.y = 0;
    stopUp = true;
    goUp = false;
}

public void stopDown() {
    acceleration.y = 0;
    stopDown = true;
    goDown = false;
}

}
```

Any ideas on how to do this with fewer lines of code? Thanks!

Comment: → [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Wow, that's great! Didn't know it existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. goRight, goLeft, goUp and goDown could be one single function called move. This function would receive a direction(between -1 and +1 to both axis) and add acceleration to velocity according to the direction received. In lieu of the stops, you could make one single function called deceleration which would test the box direction and decrease it by a constant if not zero. This function would be called every X time period. If the deceleration constant is smaller than the acceleration constant in move, it'll work. So you can do it in 2 functions.

Comment: I see. I mean, it works, but it just seemed so bulky. Thanks for the input! I'll implement it the way you described. Two functions are much better than eight.